# Read only one row in data table

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

I am writing a program with `datatable` to display this table.
[image]

In this table you can edit all columns, but I need this functionality included and only e.g. for 2 rows it is not possible to edit them.

when i try with

```
foreach (column System.Data.DataColumn in tab.Columns) column.ReadOnly = false;
```

=> all table columns are not editable.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What identifies the rows that should be read-only?

Comment: I suggest to use the above and set the condition however you need (row index, etc)